# Evaluate a Z3 expression

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a constraint in Z3py, say,

```
z3.Real('x')<=3
```

Is there a simple, built-in way to evaluate the constraint, to 'true' or 'false' for a potential model?  For example, evaluating the constraint with `z3.Real('x')->2` should give 'true'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either evaluate expressions under a model that can be extracted when Solver.check returns sat (retrieve the model using Solver.model()), or you can represent your own model as a substitution (when the model only mentions constants), and then substitute the values from the model into the expression using the 'substitute' method, then use 'simplify' to evaluate the resulting expression.

Comment: I didn't know simplify could do that! Awesome!